# My foreach-loop doesn't work

Tags: java

This method is supposed to return the object most popular friend. I though that this loop would add a object with a `getFriend().size() > 0` in an arraylist. Then it would compare the next objects `getFriend().size()` with the object which is in the ArrayList. The object would get added to the ArrayList, while the other object gets removed, if it have more friends.

```
// Class variables

// the person's name
private String name;
// a list of this person's friends
private ArrayList<Person> friends; 

public Person mostConnectedFriend(){
    for(Person f : friends){
        ArrayList<Integer> mostFriends = new ArrayList<>(); 
        int amountOfFriends = 0;
        if(getFriends().size() > amountOfFriends){
            mostFriends.remove(amountOfFriends);
            mostFriends.add(amountOfFriends);
        }
    } return null;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you describe what makes you think that it ["doesn't work"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)? What did you expect from this code to do and what did you get instead?

Comment: most "connected" friend?

Comment: friends is not initialized and in any case it would be empty so thre will be no loop.

Comment: This method is supposed to return the object most popular friend. I though that this loop would add a object with a getFriend().size() > 0 in an arraylist. Then it would compare the next objects getFriend().size() with the object which is in the ArrayList. The object would get added to the ArrayList, while the other object gets removed, if it have more friends. Sorry if I'm hard to understand.

Comment: Please avoid chatty text about your plight or your struggles that adds no information that might help us understand your actual question, and instead try to include more information that helps us to understand your code and your problem.  I've removed the "cruft" from your question but leave it up to you to add more of the needed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the code you show is inside the `Person` class, and that you're trying to find out which of `this` person's friends has the greatest number of their own friends, then this might work:

```
public Person mostConnectedFriend() {
    int highestFriendCount = 0;
    Person friendWithHighestFriendCount = null;
    for (Person friend : friends) {
        int friendCount = friend.friends.size();
        if (friendCount > highestFriendcount) {
            highestFriendCount = friendCount;
            friendWithHighestFriendCount = friend;
        }
    }
    return friendWithHighestFriendCount;
}
```

This goes through every friend of `this` Person, and each time it finds a friend who has a higher friend count than the others checked so far it replaces the count and keeps track of this current friend. By the end of the loop `friendWithHighestFriendCount` will hold the best-connected friend, and `highestFriendCount` will hold the number of friends they have.